# Facebook registration not showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration

Having problems with facebook and firefox. Namely the facebook registration popup is always empty on Firefox. I have attempted several ways of approaching the popup code but nothing is working. Can anyone shed any light on this?

The current code looks like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '254855334530300',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

[[<fb:registration redirect_uri="http://www.bymad.co.uk/deals"></fb:registration>]]
```

I have tried several variants from the facebook documentation including just a direct iframe call. They all give me a blank iframe in firefox. It works right in IE, Chrome and Opera, just firefox goofing it up.

I have also tried taking the url it generates as the iframe src and pasting that directly into a browser address bar, it loads exactly how I would expect it to.

Comment: Are you getting `Unable to load the registration form for this ID. You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: Invalid 'client_id'.)`

Comment: I am getting nothing at all. No errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check that the **sandbox mode** of your app (in the app settings) is disabled.

If the sandbox mode is enabled, the registration plugin don't work for the users other than admin- that might be your case.

Comment: The sandbox mode is disabled. I should have added that the login is on a remote site rather than on facebook itself. The fault only appears in Firefox.

Comment: Can you post the link (if its on the live server)?

Comment: The server is http://bymad.co.uk/login-register I have moved it to just display on the page at the moment, just incase it was the dialog box that was causing the problem. It should just appear on the page.

Comment: I can see the registration box in firefox too

Comment: What version of Firefox? I am using 24.0

Comment: Same. but i'm able to see. Clear the cache and then try, may be that'll work